# UML Class Diagram

Tags: uml, entity, class-diagram, boundary, ecb-pattern

I have a design class diagram using the boundary, control, entity pattern:

[image]

Are the following links allowed:

- boundary to boundary ?
- control to control?

Comment: I don't see a question among all these words. What are you asking?

Comment: i edited my post , i hope it's clearer now . :)

Comment: Umm, still not clear, and no idea where your "chart" is?

Comment: You now have the chart, but what is it that you are actually asking? Can you expand on the question some more?

Comment: @ChrisBritt His question is, whether the associations between boundaries and between controls are ok. Well, what can be said?

Comment: so ! i still searching for an answer ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ECB pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-control-boundary) is meant to ease implementation of use-cases. In its philosophy,  controls implement use cases, boundaries the relation of use cases with external world,  and entities, the business data that is managed by the use cases.

So only the following links should be allowed:

```
             Entity     Boundary   Control
Entity         X                      X
Boundary                              X
Control        X           X          X
```

You see that boundary to boundary is not allowed. Boundaries can only be linked to actors or to controls.

Control to control is allowed, but you haven't any.

An additional question is the kind of link that should be represented.  Is it really plain association (i.e. structural, one end is a property of the other) ?  Or is it a usage dependency (i.e.  a dashed line with the stereotype `<<use>>` would be more appropriate) ?  I'd opt for the first alternative between entities, but the second with controls and boundaries.

Comment: "An additional question is the kind of link that should be represented. Is it really plain association (i.e. structural, one end is a property of the other) ? Or is it a usage dependency (i.e. a dashed line with the stereotype <> would be more appropriate) ? I'd opt for the first alternative between entities, but the second with controls and boundaries. " ? i didn't understand u very well actually !! but thanks any way

Comment: I want to know why Boundary to Boundary isn't allowed. If we have two pages both using the same component such as a list item, can I link them together?

Comment: @SiegeSailor This constraint is only at high level, where a boundary corresponds to a while user interface of a use case. Of course a boudary could be decomposed into several related boundaries. I’ll update with a linked wikipedia article which explains this better under section “robustness diagram”